# Qual è il significato di "fare una parte" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto questo dialogo tra Milton, partigiano badogliano, e Némega, partigiano della Stella Rossa:

> Némega andò ad aumentare la fiamma del petrolio e tornando disse: – Che volevate farne? Scambiarlo con uno dei vostri? Quando l’hanno beccato? 
>         – Stamattina. 
>         – Dove?
>         – Sull’altro versante, verso Alba. 
>         – Come? 
>         – La nebbia. Da noi era un mare di latte.  
>         – È tuo fratello?  
>         – No. 
>         – Allora un tuo amico? Si capisce, se hai sfangato fin quassú a **fare una parte** del genere. Ma non siete capaci di darvi da fare in giro per beccarne uno?

Nel passaggio si fa riferimento al fatto che Milton era stato camminando per ore sfidando la nebbia, la pioggia, il fango e tutto tipo di pericoli per arrivare fino a un presidio della Stella Rossa, con l'obiettivo di ottenere un prigioniero nemico da scambiare col suo amico Giorgio, che era stato catturato dai fascisti.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "fare una parte del genere" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "parte" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che "fare la parte" può significare interpretare un personaggio o assumere un ruolo, ma non riesco a capire il senso di questa locuzione nel dialogo sopra citato.

Comment: credo che significhi qualcosa del tipo _" (se) ti sei dato tanto da fare..."_
o anche _" (se) hai agito in quel modo..."_ secondo me qui è un sinonimo di agire.
Guardando la definizione di http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parte/, potremmo prendere il significato 5.b o 5.c

Comment: Credo significhi "a pretendere qualcosa del genere", appena arriverò a leggere quella pagina risponderò con più cognizione di causa

Answer (score 1):

Come dice MrPk nel commento qui sopra, il significato più coerente rispetto alla frase è sicuramente quello marcato 5.c nella voce "parte" del Treccani.
Vale a dire, "una parte" in un contesto negativo (anche sottinteso) è un "allusione a comportamento o ad azione biasimevole". A mio modo di vedere questo significato deriva direttamente dal 5.b, nel senso che "fare una parte (negativa)" vorrebbe dire "tra i tanti possibili ruoli/comportamenti, adottarne uno disdicevole".
Némega si potrebbe quindi parafrasare così: "Allora un tuo amico? Si capisce, se hai [faticato] fin quassú [per fare una richiesta del genere]."

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Confermo quanto scritto, anche perché Fenoglio usa la stessa espressione anche più avanti. Ha un'accezione un po' meno dura (capire la ragione altrui) ma non giustificarla, quindi concordo con Colemar